# Need help in decoding Bitmask flags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

beginner in using bitwise operators here. I understand the differences between them, however I'm not able to decode correctly the user language from them. basically the backend gives me a number which I need to use for decoding user language.

```
static const int TlvLanguageMask = 0x0700;
static const int TlvEnglish = 0x0000;
static const int TlvFrench = 0x0100;
static const int TlvSwedish = 0x0200;
static const int TlvCzech = 0x0300;
static const int TlvGerman = 0x0400;
static const int TlvSpanish = 0x0500;
static const int TlvItalian = 0x0600;
static const int TlvRomanian = 0x0700;
```

this is what the backend written in C++ uses for setting the languages. in my frontend written in Javascript I did the following thing:

```
 function decodeLanguagevalue(Languagecode){
  let language;
  const languages={
  languagemask:1792,//1110 0000 000
  english:0,//0
  french:128<<1,//256 -->1000 0000 0
  swedish:128<<2,//512-->1000 0000 00
  czech:512^256,//768 -->1100 0000 00 french+swedish?
  German:128<<3,//1024-->1000 0000 000
  Spanish:1024^256,//1280-->1010 0000 000 german+french?
  Italian:1280^256,//1536--> 1100 0000 000 spanish+french?
  Romanian:1536^256//1792--> 1110 0000 000 italian+french?


}
  switch (Languagecode) {
    case Languagecode & languages.english:
      language="UK"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.french:
      language="French"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.swedish:
      language="Swedish"
      break;
    case Languagecode  & languages.french & languages.swedish:
      language="CZech"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.German:
      language="German"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.German & languages.french:
      language="Spanish"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.Spanish & languages.french:
      language="Italian"
      break;
    case Languagecode & languages.Italian & languages.french:
      language="Romanian" 
      break;
    default:
      language="Unknown"
      break;
  }
  return language

}
```

however this function always returns me Unknown. This basically means that I messed up with bitwise operators on the frontend.Can someone enlight me on these and help me decoding them correctly? thank you

EDIT 23/05

```
function decodeLanguagevalue(Languagecode){
  let language;
  const languages={
    languagemask:0x0700,//1110 0000 000 //0x0700
    english:0x0000,//0 //0x0000
    french:0x0100,//256 -->1000 0000 //0x0100
    swedish:0x0200,//512-->1000 0000 00 //0x0200
    czech:0x0300,//768 -->1100 0000 00  //0x0300
    German:0x0400,//1024-->1000 0000 000 //0x0400
    Spanish:0x0500,//1280-->1010 0000 000  //0x0500
    Italian:0x0600,//1536--> 1100 0000 000 //0x0600
    Romanian:0x0700//1792--> 1110 0000 000  //0x0700
  }
  
  if((Languagecode & languages.english)==languages.english){
    language='English'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.french)==languages.french){
    language='French'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.swedish)==languages.swedish){
    language='Swedish'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.czech)==languages.czech){
    language='Czech'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.German)==languages.German){
    language='German'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.Spanish)==languages.Spanish){
    language='Spanish'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.Italian)==languages.Italian){
    language='Italian'
  }
  if((Languagecode & languages.Romanian)==languages.Romanian){
    language='Romanian'
  }

  language===undefined ? language='unknown' : language
  
  return language
  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `switch...case` statement is that it checks that `Languagecode` is equal to `Languagecode & languages.english`, which can only be true when `languages.english` has *at least* all 1-bits that `Languagecode` has, but if `Languagecode` also includes non-language related bits (outside of the language mask range), this can never be true. The same then happens with the other `case` parts of the `switch` statement...

I would do this:

```
const languages = ["English", "French", "Swedish", "Czech", "German", "Spanish", "Italian", "Romanian"];

function decodeLanguagevalue( code ) {
  const languageId = (code >> 8) & 7; // get the three bits of interest in the lowest bits
  return languages[languageId];
}
```

#### Explanation

Initially, the language id is encoded in the three bits marked as `*` in the below integer (in binary representation -- this corresponds to your `languagemask`):

```
???? ?*** ???? ????
```

The question marks indicate bits that do not interest us when it comes to finding out the language. So we start by "removing" the bits at the right side of those that interest us. We can shift them out, using the right-shift operator (`>>`). If we shift once, we get this:

```
0??? ??** *??? ????
───────────────────>>
```

Note how at the left side a zero is shifted *in*, and at the right side a `?` is *dropped off*.

If we continue to shift (up to 8 times), we get this:

```
0000 0000 ???? ?***
───────────────────>>
```

As we are not interested in the `?` part on the left side either, we kick those out as well, by applying a bit-wise AND operation with 0111:

```
0000 0000 ???? ?***
0000 0000 0000 0111
─────────────────── AND
0000 0000 0000 0***
```

So now we have extracted the three bits of interest, and they sit in the least significant bits. That is great, because now the *value* of the number lies between 0 and 7 (inclusive). This can be used as an index in an array of strings.

Comment: @EdoardoRemondini as an aside, trincot's answer is more to the point, but am not sure whether your code represents a minimal framework of what you are attempting to accomplish.  Ie, are you planning to have more logic for each case statement unique to the language?  If so, even with trincot's solution, you can have a separate array (or create an array of objects with the necessary attributes) consisting of different functions which contain language specific logic.  That is, language specific functions which are called from within `decodeLanguagevalue` once the `languageId` is identified...

Comment: No, I'm not planning to have additional logic for each case statement.however the thing that I do not understand is the >> operator. I know that shifts the number that I passed in by 8 bits, so one byte. In the answer he states that I need to get the three bits of interest... That's the thing I don't understand, because I have really a huge lack of knowledge about bits and this bitwise operators...

Comment: @EdoardoRemondini, so the `TlvLanguageMask` of 0x0700 (which is hex) is in binary 0000 0111 0000 0000.  The right shift (ie, >> ) of 8 bits shifts that binary number to 0000 0000 0000 0111, leaving a range of 0 to 7 (after ANDing with 7, to ensure that any other higher order bits are cleared), which in trincot's answer is used to index the `languages` array.  And since you don't have any other logic in the `switch...case` statement other than translating the bits to a string, then this should be the answer to run with.  (And in that case, you can make this answer the accepted answer...)

Comment: hi @Trentium and sorry for late reply but I have a question. so the bitmask is what tells me the number of bites i'm interested in right? in my case the bitmask is 1792 which in binary is 000 0000 0111. I pop the zero out of it with >>8(why eight? is it because the number of zero's in the mask are eight? let me know please). the result of this is the number 7. then why anding again?

Comment: The bitmask 1792 in binary is 111 0000 0000 (not what you wrote). With the `>>8` you pop out bits at the right side of that number. Since there are 8 trailing zeroes in 111 0000 0000, you will get 111 as result (in binary). You need to AND again, because there might be other bits to the *left* of the original number that we want to ignore, as they don't belong to the language part (see the question marks in my answer, which represent bits that can be 0 or 1, but in which we have no interest). Just read the "explanation" part in my answer... it covers this.

Answer (score 2):

The code as presented encodes the Languagecode as a combination of a bit mask, and a numeric value in the range from 0 to 7.  (Note that in binary, the range is 000b to 111b.)  Thus, the bit mask is used to reduce the Languagecode to only the 3 binary digits of interest.  Then, you simply check the result against the Languagecode value.

Thus, on the client side, the code will appear as...

```
 const TlvLanguageMask = 0x0700;
 const TlvEnglish = 0x0000;
 const TlvFrench = 0x0100;
    o
    o
    o
 const TlvRomanian = 0x0700;

function decodeLanguagevalue( Languagecode ) {

  let language = 'Unknown';
  switch ( Languagecode & TlvLanguageMask ) {
    case TlvEnglish:
      language = 'English';
      break;
    case TlvFrench:
      language = 'French';
      break;
        o
        o
        o
    case TlvRomanian:
      language = 'Romanian'; 
      break;
  }
  return language;

}
```

Comment: so I need the mask to turn on/turn off the bits that are in excess and then compare it with the values the give me?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I used.(I didn't read the replies here till today). It seems to work only if I check languages in order. from English to Romanian. otherwise the results are not accurate with certain numbers